# AttributeError: module 'allauth.models' has no attribute 'Group'

Tags: python, django

views.py
I use django-allauth. Before migrate this code was working.After migrations, he refers to Groups and gives an error

```
def teachers(request):
    group = models.Group.objects.get(name='teachers')
    list_teachers = group.user_set.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'teachers.html',
        {
            'list_teachers' : list_teachers
        }
    )
```

```
Internal Server Error: /teachers/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python 3.7.4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python 3.7.4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\python 3.7.4\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Homie\Desktop\defenseMilestone\defense\milestone\views.py", line 55, in teachers
    group = models.Group.objects.get(name='teachers')
AttributeError: module 'allauth.models' has no attribute 'Group'
[13/Dec/2019 16:50:51] "GET /teachers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 66823
```

Comment: looks like you have a naming conflict. Do you really want to refer to `allauth.models`?

Comment: I'm using allauth and i want to divide my users to teachers and students. when I checked that the user is a member of the teacher group, this error occurs.

Comment: Where is `models` imported (which you use to get `Group`)? You need to import `Group` from `django.contrib.auth.models` not from `allauth.models`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to import `Group` from `allauth.models` but `allauth` doesn't define `Group`. Import it from `django.contrib.auth.models` as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
def teachers(request):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='teachers')
    list_teachers = group.user_set.all()
    return render(
        request,
        'teachers.html',
        {
            'list_teachers' : list_teachers
        }
    )
```

Please try this one.

Comment: The problem is where to import from, not necessarily with the `teachers()` method itself. So if you add where you get `Group` from, it would serve as a better answer.

Comment: Please always explain in your answer, not just showing code.

Comment: Okay sir, noted. Thank you